# Некорректный ответ на запрос Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, postgresql9.5

При запросе руками в консоли

```
@Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "select CASE cl.CL_Const \n" +
                    "        WHEN 1 THEN 'Куп' \n" +
                    "        WHEN 2 THEN 'Ном' \n" +
                    "        ELSE 'Unknown' \n" +
                    "        END as CL_Const, \n" +
                    "from DB.db.Cl cl \n" +
                    "where 1=1 \n" +
                    " and cl.created_date >= :createdDate \n" +
                    " and cl.created_date < :endDate" )
    List<Coup> selectCoup(@Param("createdDate" ) String createdDate,
                              @Param("endDate" ) String endDate);
```

Получаю ответ из БД с разными вариантами строк. Как 'Куп', так и 'Ном'. Собственно, как и лежит в моей базе.

Но при запуске уже из Idea, список List содержит только 'Куп' значения. Общее количество строк в ответе из БД совпадает, но строки, там где в БД 'Ном' - перезаписываются в 'Куп' при работе с Hibernate.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
@NoArgsConstructor 
@AllArgsConstructor 
@Data 
@Entity 
public class Coup {
@Column(name = "CL_Const")     
private String CL_Const;
}
```

Comment: покажите класс `Coup`

Comment: `@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
public class Coup {

    @Column(name = "CL_Const")
    private String CL_Const;

}`